# Show stack trace in Rails 4 app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack-trace

I've tried uncommenting the following line in production.rb, and setting it to true, to no avail:

`config.consider_all_requests_local = false`

How can I see the stack trace in production?

Comment: try seting the value to `true` in the `config/environments/production.rb` file: `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try and the result was the same.

Comment: Consider using bug tracker software like bugsnag or airbrake. They will give you a lot better bug tracking experience.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using one but it's not picking the error up (although the Bugsnag rake task works).

Comment: yeah, bugsnag is great for bugtracking. I have moved to bugsnag from airbrake. And it's performing really well.